# Making Crystal reports "DocuSign-able" at run time

Tags: crystal-reports, docusignapi

We produce Crystal Reports from our two main legacy systems, we would like to make them DocuSign-able, meaning that when we send them out they follow a "workflow" of signatures...We have not found any solution to that in the API Documentation

Comment: do you have a way to export the Crystal report into a PDF, HTML, or an image file? these formats can be used to produce a DocuSignable form.

Answer (score 0):

Would a single digital signature be enough for your workflow, or do you need multiple signatures?